# Ways to Poison HTML5 Appcache in phone-gap hybrid apps?

Tags: html, caching, cordova

I have a hybrid application developed with Phone-gap. The application does not make use of iFrames (uses ChildBrowser) and has strong XSS prevention mechanism. This app caches .js resource for offline use.

I was looking into various ways in which HTML5 AppCached resources could be poisoned. With the above scenario, (i.e., no iFrame, no possible XSS) is there any way of poisoning these HTML5 Appcached resources?

Comment: This is a good question. I'd say "NO, it's not possible" (with some security background), but I'll wait for _true experts_ to answer. :)